# A curve with two specific asymptotic lines

Tags: asymptotics, curves, uniform-continuity, tangent-line, planar-graphs

Consider two planar lines. How can I find a continuous curve with to specific asymptotic lines, as shown in figure.
[Planar curve with two asymptotic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/johJ4.jpg)

Comment: They are an infinity if such curves, for example hyperbola. Change the system of axes so that the asymptotes be the new axes (translation, rotation and affine transformation). Then a lot of functions of the kind $y=\frac{\alpha}{x^\beta}$ are convenient. Determine $\alpha$ and $\beta$ by fitting (regression).

Comment: Dear  JJacquelin, Thanks for the comment.The proposed function has two orthogonal asymptotic lines which is special case.

Comment: So, it's even simpler: Change the system of axes $(x,y)$ so that the asymptotes be the new axes and fit as said above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution to this problem is not unique. If $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ are functions describing your lines, then for example $g(x)=-\frac{1}{\alpha}\log\left(e^{-\alpha f_1(x)}+e^{-\alpha f_2(x)}\right)$ would be a smooth curve below both lines with given asymptotes for any $\alpha>0$, as in your figure.

Comment: Dear Stefan Böttner, Thanks for your prompt reply. Your answer is excellent and very useful. Best regards, M.T. Abadi